# SQL Sub-Query performance issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm having performance issues with my SQL sub query.

As a hard-coded query, it takes about 1 second to run:

```
SELECT   ColumnA
        ,ColumnB
        ,ColumnC
FROM    [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[View]
WHERE   ColumnA IN 
    (
        'ABC',
        'DEF',
        'HIJ',
        'KLM'
    )
```

However, the following code takes over a minute to run:

```
SELECT   ColumnA
        ,ColumnB
        ,ColumnC
FROM    [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[View]
WHERE   ColumnA IN 
    (
        SELECT ColumnA FROM #TempTable
    )
```

The temp table contains the same 4 rows as the hard-coded example. The view on the linked server contains approx. 700,000 rows (and, unfortunately, is outside of my control). The ColumnA data types are the same and both tables are indexed.

Any ideas on how to improve the performance of this query?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is 'ColumnA' From #TempTable a varchar type or nvarchar?

Comment: Hi Randy, it's a varchar field.

Comment: Can you please post execution plan for the query, that might reveal the issue, another thing if linked server login does not have enough rights it might not have retrieved statistics.

Comment: The remote server suppliers ran several tests themselves in order to determine whether me having enhanced privileges would help - the answer they came back with was "no, it wouldn't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT   V.ColumnA
        ,V.ColumnB
        ,V.ColumnC
FROM    [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[View] V
INNER JOIN #TempTable T ON V.ColumnA = T.ColumnA
```

Comment: Hi RedFilter, I've tried this but the performance is just as bad, if not worse.

Comment: The join will be similar performance to the IN. You could, however, try a remote hint (ie: INNER REMOTE JOIN #TempTable), especially if the temp table contains significantly less rows than the linked server view. See here: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/quering/speeding-up-the-query

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I've now tried INNER REMOTE JOIN and it does improve performance significantly. The query takes approx. 10 seconds to run, down from over a minute, which is better but still not great. I've contacted the owner of the linked server to discuss the permissions as per your other post.

Comment: Brian - many thanks for the INNER REMOTE JOIN suggestion. The linked server supplier has provided me with an alternative source which, combined with the INNER REMOTE JOIN hint returns the records almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably related to how the query plan is created. In one case SQL server knows what values it will be using in the comparison, in the second it is estimating.
Run each query in a seperate Management Studio window after clicking the "Include Actual Excecution Plan." You will probably see different plans.
The first thing I would check is to hover over the arrows linking the actions (start with the fat ones) and compare the Estimated number of Rows to the Actual number of rows. A large disparity (factor of 10?) in these values can cause SQL server to make the wrong decision (table scan vs index etc.) If you see this you might consider a hint to get SQL to change its plan - if you need to use the slow query! The big problem with hints is that as the data volumes change the hint can easily become a hindrance rather that a benefit, so they are considered to be a last resort.

Comment: This could be related to the linked server login not having sufficient remote permissions to obtain the necessary statistics to build a decent plan. "Users that have limited permissions on any columns of the table might not have sufficient permissions to obtain all the useful statistics, and might receive a less efficient query plan and experience poor performance." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I totally missed the reference to the "Linked" Server :(

Comment: Thanks, Pat/Brian - I'm liaising with the linked server supplier to see if I can get enhanced privileges.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to get the linked server supplier to enhance privileges so while this could be the cause of the main problem, they've provided me with an alternative table source rather than a view.

Answer (score 0):

The linked server supplier has provided me with a different source. Instead of connecting to a view (which itself was spread over multiple servers), I now connect to a single table. This, combined with Brian's INNER REMOTE JOIN suggestion returns the full dataset almost immediately.

Whilst it's a little frustrating that I couldn't follow the enhanced privileges/linked server options, at least this query is working well.

Many thanks for everyone's help!